# The Simple and Correct Way to Add User Meta

Tags: users, user-meta

I want to give points to users to their activities like writing posts, writing comments,  etc.

I thought to use user meta to store points.

I know that I can use add_user_meta...

But the problem is,  there are many ways to register a user for my site like normal reg form,  buddypress reg form,  Admins can add via admin panel and many more.

So it is hard to add add_user_meta to every where.

Is they any way to add a user meta for all current users and future uses with a default value?

Comment: I actually don't get the problem. Why having many forms of registration have an impact on how you use an API?

Comment: @Mark Thanks for the comment. I have to call add_user_meta functions in every registration options..  Even I have to call it when users are added via admin panel. Because of I have more than 7 registration options it is little bit hard to add it every where. That is my problem.

Comment: also worth checking out some of the mycred and other points plugin code to see where they hook into for awarding points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to detect when a UI was triggered, is indeed the wrong general approach (unless you want to tie to the UI). A proper one will be to hook on the [user_register](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) action.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'wpse223196_registration_save', 10, 1 );

function wpse223196_registration_save( $user_id ) {

   add_user_meta($user_id, 'score', 5);

}
```